# Что лучше: Ненавязчивый Ajax или обычный Ajax-запрос к форме?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2015

Вот два кода, помогите сравнить, и с чем лучше работать?

1 Ненавязчивый Ajax

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
    <div>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("Email", "Введите E-mail")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("Password", "Введите Password")
        </div>

        <div>
            <button id="buttonLogIn" type="submit">LOG IN</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        //alert("Запрос был успешно выполнен. Получены следующие данные: \n" + data);
        var text = document.getElementById('UrlAddress').value;
        $(location).attr('href', text);
    }
</script>
```

2 Ajax-запрос к форме

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormLogIn" }))
    {
        <div>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

            <div>
                    @Html.TextBox("Email", "Введите E-mail")
            </div>

            <div>
                    @Html.TextBox("Password", "Введите Password")
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id="buttonLogIn" type="submit">LOG IN</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#buttonLogIn").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#FormLogIn").serialize(),
                    url: '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")',
                    success: function () {
                        var text = document.getElementById('UrlAddress').value;
                        $(location).attr('href', text);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

+ Я правильно понял, что если хочу ajax в любом виде, то методы в контроллерах должны быть обычными, никакими не асинхронными (async/await)?

Comment: а чем эти два кода отличаются?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, потому что на первый никто не ответил :-)

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос, теперь отличаются)

Comment: @PavelMayorov уже нету)

Comment: Что такое UrlAddress  и откуда там берутся данные?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov UrlAddress - не сильно важная вещь) Это нужно для того, чтобы запоминать с какой страницы был переход, и после Логина вернутся обратно на страницу с которой был редирект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работайте так, как вам проще.

Достоинства "ненавязчивого" ajax:

- выглядит проще;
- сложнее допустить ошибку.

Достоинства обычного ajax:

- можно принимать ответы в формате json, а не только куски html;
- не засоряется глобальное пространство имен обработчиками событий.

Обращаю внимание, что вы в своем коде умудрились допустить аж две ошибки:

- надо подписываться не на событие клика по кнопке - а на событие `submit` у формы. Это позволит отправлять форму по нажатию Enter;
- Обертка `$(document).ready(function () {` тут лишняя, она лишь создает период времени, когда форма не работает.

---

По поводу связи ajax и асинхронных методов контроллера - не придумывайте. Браузер ничего не знает про то, синхронные или асинхронные методы в контроллере и знать не может. Это - деталь реализации на стороне сервера. Можете обработчики ajax-вызовов хоть на php писать.

Comment: Очень исчерпывающе) Спасибо! У меня две формы на одной, поэтому если отправить по нажатию Enter, тогда отправится все сразу, поэтому и работаю Ajax'ом по кнопкам.

Comment: @YanLinkin в смысле? Форма внутри формы? Не делайте так

Comment: нашел инфу про: **"Обертка $(document).ready(function () { тут лишняя, она лишь создает период времени, когда форма не работает."** Тут : (http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/10.2.php) в разделе **"Функция jQuery"**. Там есть пару вариантов, которые могут быть; я думал это все обычные сокращения одной и той же функции, поэтому выбрал любую :)

Comment: @YanLinkin забудьте то, что написано на той странице. Прочитал пару абзацев - там бред полный. Лучше читайте документацию: https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: не так выразился. Есть **View**, оно содержит две **PartialView**, у каждой по своей **Ajax.BeginForm()**. И одновременно выводятся на экран, поэтому Enter по **submit'у** - хороший совет, запишу его, но не в этот раз).

Comment: @YanLinkin если формы отдельные - то и события submit будут приходить им раздельно.

Comment: Т.е. какую форму я сейчас редактирую, тот submit и активен для нее?

Comment: @YanLinkin что значит "активен"? Если текстовый курсор находится в поле ввода - то нажатие Enter отправит тут форму, к которой относится поле ввода.

Comment: А эти функции идентичны:$(document).ready(function(){}) и **$(function(){ })** ? (инфа с того же метанита)

Comment: @YanLinkin да, но вам не нужна ни одна из них